# Web API - HTTP Post Request That Includes Header & Body

Tags: php, ajax, api, http, http-post

I just got API access for one of the website on the internet, and as a new api developer i got into troubles understanding how should i start and with what, So hope you guys guide me . They don't have Documents or tutorials Yet.

If anyone can give me a small example on how to send Http post request that includes Header and body? As what they are mentioning in the API page:

> All requests must include an Authorization header with siteid and
>   apikey (with a colon in between) and it must match with the siteid and
>   apikey in the request body

In the body the Parameter content type will be application/json. They have also provided a Base URL.

The response will be as application/json.

What should i do? is the request can be sent using AJAX? or there is PHP code for this? i have been reading a lot about this subject but none enter my head. Really hope you guys help me out .

Please let me know if you need more information so i can provide it to you.

**EDIT :** Problem solved and just posting the small editing that i did to the code that was provided in the correct answer that i marked .

Thanks to Mr. Anonymous for the big help that he gave me . His answer was so so close, all what i had to do is just edit his code a little bit and everything went good .

I will list the finial code down bellow in case any other developer had this issue or wanted to do an HTTP request .

First what i did is that i stored the data that i wanted to send over the HTTP in a file with a JSON type :

```
{
  "criteria": {
    "landmarkId": 181,
    "checkInDate": "2018-02-25",
    "checkOutDate": "2018-02-30"
  }
}
```

Second thing as what guys can see what Mr. Anonymous posted .

```
<?php 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$SiteID= 'My Site Id';
$ApiId= 'My Api Id';
$url = 'Base URL';

// Here i will get the data that i created in Json data type
$data = file_get_contents("data.json");

// I guess this step in not required cause the data are already in JSON but i had to do it for myself  
$arrayData = json_decode($data, true);

$ch = curl_init();
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$SiteID:$ApiID");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                            'Content-Type: application/json',
                                            'Connection: Keep-Alive',
                                            'Authorization: $SiteID:$ApiId'
                                            ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($arrayData)); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);  
print_r($result); 

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
    $site_id = 'your_site_id';
    $api_key = 'your_api_key';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api-connect-url');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    ############  Only one of the statement as per condition ########### 

   //if they have asked for post
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$site_id=$api_key" );

    //or if they have asked for raw post
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$site_id:$api_key" );

    ####################################################################

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["$site_id:$api_key"] );

    $api_response = curl_exec ($ch);

    curl_close ($ch);
```

**As asker need to send JSON Payload to API**

```
    $site_id = 'your_site_id';
    $api_key = 'your_api_key';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api-connect-url');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    //send json payload
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{
        "criteria":{
            "cityId":9395,
            "area":{
                "id":0,
                "cityId":0
            },
            "landmarkId":0,
            "checkInDate":"2017-09-02",
            "checkOutDate":"2017-09-03",
            "additional":{
                "language":"en-us",
                "sortBy":"PriceAsc",
                "maxResult":10,
                "discountOnly":false,
                "minimumStarRating":0,
                "minimumReviewScore":0,
                "dailyRate":{
                    "minimum":1,
                    "maximum":10000
                },
                "occupancy":{
                    "numberOfAdult":2,
                    "numberOfChildren":1
                },
                "currency":"USD"
                }
            }
        }"
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["$site_id:$api_key", 'Content-Type:application/json'] );

    $api_response = curl_exec ($ch);

    curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: His sir , thx for comment, but have a Q , as what they are mentioning, the header and the Body are required, so i guess the request wont work without the body right ? http://prntscr.com/iiehk7

Comment: try raw post. Can you share links to documentation or some more details?

Comment: Thats the issue sir , no documentation or something, but i will send you what they are requesting. one min

Comment: you need to send JSON payload to the API, site id and API key must be there according to screenshot. Provide complete JSON body thought copyable medium like https://pastebin.com etc

Comment: Ok sir , give me a min let me do it for you, thank you so much for the help .

Comment: The request response will be in JSON as they mentioned as well

Comment: As soon as i get the problem solved i will mark the You answer . :D

Comment: Its not clear that where and how in JSON siteid and apikey has to be provided. Try adding like this. https://pastebin.com/X3xtEfrx. You need to ask them for exact placement of site id and API key in JSON payload. Or search in documents. It must be mentioned somewhere

Comment: true its no clear , lets say that i added it , how to send the data? its JSON type , how you want me to send it ? AJAX ? PHP ?

Comment: Ok sir waiting for it :d

Comment: for some reasons it gives me " is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500" well i will have to investigate the problem . thank you kind sir .